# Point-in-time build with Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, build

Say I have modifiers in version numbers like "3.+" instead of specific version like "3.1.5"

Then Gradle picks the latest artifact within the current major version. Sometimes this creates a problem when something in the dependency tree changes and breaks the build / runtime.

In such cases, I would want to specify a date and have the tool pick whatever artifact "3.+" would have pointed to on that date. Same with all its dependencies.

Is it possible?

Comment: See https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-dependency-lock-plugin

Comment: Why not specify a real version number then?

Comment: In hindsight that makes sense. Unfortunately, when I wrote the build file, I thought it was cool that gradle would keep my application up to date. It worked for well over two years. Didn't have to compile for last six months. Now its breaking at run-time. Nothing has changed in the code, so it's the dependencies that have and I don't know which one exactly.

Comment: Browse the maven repo to discover what was the actual version of those artefacts when you last compiled it successfully (or look in the released product you built at that time), and go back to hard-coded versions.

Comment: Yup doing just that

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet possible with pure `gradle` but it's on the roadmap. But as lance-java suggested, the nebula dependency-lock-plugin is made exactly for this use case.